# Why is this not a space-filling curve?

Tags: analysis, plane-curves

From Wikipedia, **a *space-filling curve* is a curve (i.e. a continuous function whose domain is the unit interval $[0,1]$) whose range contains the entire 2-dimensional unit square.**

Many examples of space-filling curves are known, such as the Peano curve

[image: Image credit: Wikipedia]

and the Hilbert curve

[image: Image credit: Wikipedia]

(both curves are the limiting curves of the iteration seen in the pictures).

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#History, the Peano curve was the first example of a space-filling curve to be found (by Peano). Presumably, when searching for a space-filling curve with an iterative approach in mind, Peano must have come across this curve as well:

[image]

(and so on), which has a much simpler description than the one he actually chose and, indeed, would be easy to think of even for a child (call it the "accordion curve").

This leaves two possibilities:

1. Peano chose the Peano curve for a reason other than merely it being a space-filling curve **or**, more likely
2. The "accordion curve" shown in this post is *not* a space-filling curve.

**Which is it?** If the accordion curve is space-filling, it is surely the easiest space-filling curve to describe and understand, so I strongly suspect that it is not space-filling after all. At the same time, though, I have been unable to find a reason why it should not be.

Comment: Your "accordion curve" is not continuous, because the image of an arbitrarily small interval in $[0,1]$ must span the entire vertical range of the square.

Comment: So in other words, it's not that it is not space-filling, but that it is not a (continuous) curve? That looks like the answer to me. It's of course continuous in every iteration, but not in the limit...

Comment: @limulus: The limit doesn't even exist.  Your iterations of the "accordion curve" don't converge, not even pointwise.  The iterations of the Hilbert and Peano curves converge uniformly, so the limit is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the answer by Rahul Narain: the accordion construction does not work. In order to obtain a continuous curve in the limit, there must be a modulus of continuity $\omega$ which works for every  stage  of construction: that is, $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\le \omega(|x-y|)$ for every $n$. In particular, $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\le 1/2$ when $|x-y|<\delta$, where $\delta>0$ is independent of $n$. Then the inverse image of each vertical line segment in the accordion must have length $\ge \delta$, which leads to  a contradiction as $n$ increases.